# What are these small features on the corners of a camera sensor?

Tags: sensor, digital

These are the images, my microscope suffers from some pretty large chromatic aberration, so dont trust all of the colors completely.
[image: one of the unknown features]
[image: other unknown feature]

The sensor in question is an IMX585 sensor, from a player one astronomy Uranus-C.

In the corner of it, I noticed some very small features with my microscope. They are arranged in a grid pattern, and each one is only 50 or so micron wide. There are two different arrangements, which are on each side of the sensor, totaling 4.

What are these patterns, and what is their function?

I apologize if this is not completely on topic, its about a camera sensor, but I dont know if this specific element on the sensor has any relevance to photography, since I dont know what it is, which is why I am asking the question in the first place.

Comment: probably large-area sensitive sensors for metering or autofocus.